# How do i scale the circles in my d3 leaflet solution to the frequency of long/lat combinations?

Tags: html, d3.js, leaflet

So i am learning d3 and trying to draw a map using leaflet.
My data contains some thousand lattidude and longitudes. I was able to draw circles on a leaflet map in d3.  How can i scale the size of these circles to the number of times a certain combination appears in my data?

Heres my src code up untill now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js and the geo projection plugin -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Leaflet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<div id="mapid"></div>

<style>
#mapid { height: 2000px; }
</style>
<script>

var map = L
  .map('mapid')
  .setView([52.5200, 13.4050], 5);   // center position + zoom

// Add a tile to the map = a background. Comes from OpenStreetmap
L.tileLayer(
    'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 14,
    }).addTo(map)

L.svg().addTo(map);


d3.csv("longAndLat.csv", function(data) {

    d3.select("#mapid")
    .select("svg")
    .selectAll("myCircles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).x })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).y })
        .attr("r", 12)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("fill-opacity", .2)

// Function that update circle position if something change
function update() {
  d3.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).x })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).y })
}

// If the user change the map (zoom or drag), I update circle position:
map.on("moveend", update)

});
</script>
```

I got the following result:
[Circles drawn from my data on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPBjh.png)
How can i scale these circles to the frequency in which they appear?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend that you use the latest version of D3, which is V7 rather than V4. That way, you can use `d3.group`, to group your data in all kinds of ways. The code you have seems to work fine with V7, so you can do something like so:

```
let positions = [
  {sub_district_lat: 59.3293, sub_district_long:18.0686},
  {sub_district_lat: 59.9139, sub_district_long:10.7522},
  {sub_district_lat: 59.3293, sub_district_long:18.0686},
];
let data = Array.from(
  d3.group(positions, o => [
    o.sub_district_lat, o.sub_district_long
  ].toString()))
  .map(a => ({
    cnt: a[1].length,
    sub_district_lat: a[1][0].sub_district_lat, sub_district_long: a[1][0].sub_district_long
  }));
```

Note that I've made up a few points to emulate your data.  Here it is in action:

```js
var map = L
  .map('mapid')
  .setView([59.5, 14], 5);   // center position + zoom

// Add a tile to the map = a background. Comes from OpenStreetmap
L.tileLayer(
    'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 14,
    }).addTo(map)

L.svg().addTo(map);

    let positions = [
      {sub_district_lat: 59.3293, sub_district_long:18.0686},
      {sub_district_lat: 59.9139, sub_district_long:10.7522},
      {sub_district_lat: 59.3293, sub_district_long:18.0686},
    ];
    let data = Array.from(
      d3.group(positions, o => [
        o.sub_district_lat, o.sub_district_long
      ].toString()))
      .map(a => ({
        cnt: a[1].length,
        sub_district_lat: a[1][0].sub_district_lat, sub_district_long: a[1][0].sub_district_long
      }));

    d3.select("#mapid")
    .select("svg")
    .selectAll("myCircles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).x })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).y })
        .attr("r", d => 12*d.cnt)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("fill-opacity", .2)

// Function that update circle position if something change
function update() {
  d3.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).x })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.sub_district_lat, d.sub_district_long]).y })
}

// If the user change the map (zoom or drag), I update circle position:
map.on("moveend", update)
```

```css
#mapid { height: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Leaflet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<div id="mapid"></div>
```